# Call a function from dictionary by outputting numbers as strings in quotes

Tags: python, string, function, dictionary

I have a dictionary that I want to use to call a function. My problem is, that the input needed for the function must be in quotes. My dict is like this:

```
dict = {
    'test': [10, 14, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48]
}
```

and my function has to get these numbers like this:

```
testfunction(["10", "14", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48"])
```

Is there a good - maybe Pythonic - way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you probably should just change `testfunction`.

If that's impossible, you can use `list(str(n) for n in dict["test"])`, which transforms the given dictionary into a list of strings, and pass it as the argument to `testfunction`.